# Restrictions on $n$ for a $(n,k)$ Reed-Solomon code?

Tags: coding-theory

I'm a little confused about the restrictions on $n$ for a $(n,k)$ Reed-Solomon code constructed over $GF(2^8)$. Some sources (on using RS code for error correction) claim that the max $n$ value is 255:

> Given a symbol size s, the maximum codeword length $n$ for a Reed-Solomon code is $n = 2^s - 1$. For example, the maximum length of a code with 8-bit symbols (s=8) is 255 bytes. [(link)](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eguyb/realworld/reedsolomon/reed_solomon_codes.html)

> ...the length of the resulting protected block: this is always 255 bytes... More generally, the length is $2^s-1$, where $s$ is the symbol size in bits. [(link)](https://berthub.eu/articles/posts/reed-solomon-for-programmers/)

However, in a popular implementation of RS (as an erasure code), the maximum $n$ value is set to 256, as shown by the assertion statement on line $428$ [(link)](https://github.com/tahoe-lafs/zfec/blob/master/zfec/fec.c#L428).

Based on my understanding, to use RS as an erasure code ([1](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Esuman/courses/740/papers/rizzo97ccr.pdf), [2](https://destevez.net/2017/01/an-erasure-code-based-on-vandermonde-matrices/)), we need a Vandermonde matrix $G$ of size $n \times k$, which has $n$ linearly-independent rows. The original message $x$ of $k$ symbols can then be encoded into $n$ symbols via $y = Gx$. If we receive $k$ of the elements in $y$ with known positions as $y'$, we can select the corresponding $k$ rows in $G$ to form $G'$, and construct the original $k$ message symbols via $x = {G'}^{-1}y'$. In this case, I don't see why can't $n = 256$, since we have 256 distinct field elements in $GF(2^8)$ which can form the required rows of the matrix $G$.

Furthermore, it seems like that when RS over $GF(2^8)$ is used as an error correction code, $n$ must be *equal* to $255$ (if the message has fewer than $255$ symbols, then we agree on a zero-padding that doesn't have to be explicitly transmitted). However, it seems like there's nothing stopping $n$ from being set to any value between $1$ and $256$ for the Vandermonde matrix erasure coding approach.

So what are the actual restrictions on $n$? Is it different for when the RS code is used for error correction or erasure coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the time to look/decipher at the implementation details on those sites. Yet, I'm willing to hazard a guess that the source restricting the length of the block to 255 bytes is using RS-codes as *cyclic codes.* In other words, they specify an RS-code using a generator polynomial $g(x)$.

- This has the advantage that storing $g(x)$ takes a lot less space than the largish Vandermonde matrix will. May be just something like 20 bytes as opposed to a 20x256 table of bytes.
- Using the RS-code cyclically relies on a (cyclic) subgroup of the multiplicative group of the field $GF(256)$. The entire multiplicative group has 255 elements.
- But, it should be possible to *extend* a cyclic code intelligently by adding an extra check symbol. Like if we don't use $1$ as a zero of $g(x)$, then we gain $+1$ in minimum distance by adding an overall check sum to those 255 bytes, and can still call the resulting code an RS-code.
- However, such an extension may require some modifications to the error-correction procedure.

> There is a well known and very attractive implementation of RS-codes based on cyclicity. Such an implementation needs to restrict the block length to 255 bytes. My somewhat educated guess is that this explains the differences you have observed.

It should not (but may, depending on implementation details) make any difference whether the code is used for correcting errors only or errors and erasures. Of course, the latter requires a slightly more complicated algorithm. So a downloadable package of software may be missing that.